# spring security CSRF protection

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

I read in spring [documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/)  that logout need to be submitted using post method.Something like :

```
<c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/problemSolution/logout"/>
<form action="${logoutUrl}" id="logout" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('logout').submit();">Logout</a>
```

Why is it so ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62769/must-login-and-logout-action-have-csrf-protection

Answer (score 0):

Because if it's a GET then someone else can log you out, which is annoying.

You go to `compromised.com`

They run a script that makes a GET request to `yourbank.com/logout`

You are logged out of `yourbank.com`